# What were the criteria used in the MCU to determine who\what could be snapped?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe

Within the MCU, has it ever been canonically confirmed by sources inside the universe, or supplementary material in the real world (For example, guide books or interviews with the directors) what criteria were used to determine if something could\could not be snapped?

For example, was it limited to intelligent creatures and if so what was the bar for intelligence?

Could artificial lifeforms such as Vision be snapped, or wholly robotic ones such as Ultron or the LMD from Agent's of shield?

Comment: The scene in Endgame where Hawkeye's family is snapped depicts singing birds that mysteriously go silent so we know it did happen to animals.

Comment: I'd always thought that this was more for dramatic effect.

Comment: Nope. 50% of all life.

Comment: Not an answer, but I would have thought robotic lifeforms such as Ultron or the LMDs, since they are not "alive" in any way and simply objects following (very complex) instructions, would not be snapped. An artificial lifeform such as Vision, being living and breathing and made of flesh, could be.

Comment: Indeed, the Eternals, being robots weren't snapped either.

Comment: @user25730 Vision is made entirely of vibranium isn't he?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, all "animal" life.

From [**this answer**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186884/does-thanos-plan-apply-to-higher-order-beings) over on SF&F

> According to Marvel producer Kevin Feige Thanos' 'finger snap' resulted in the destruction of **half of all life in the universe, not just higher beings.**
>
> > **Q. Are half the animals dead? Are half of the horses gone? Half of the ants?**
> >
> > **Feige:** *Yes! Yes. All life.*
> >
> > <sub><sup>[Kevin Feige Still Won’t Tell Us All Marvel’s Future Plans](https://birthmoviesdeath.com/2018/07/08/kevin-feige-still-wont-tell-us-all-marvels-future-plans)</sup></sub>